# why fetch api adding escape characters in url %E2%80%8B

Tags: reactjs, url, react-redux, fetch

Im calling fetch api in react service when I give static string to fetch it works fine like following

```
export const getAll = async (_url) => {
 const requestOptions = {
method: 'GET',
};

 try {
  const response = await fetch(
  process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/api/communications/notifications/',  // like this
  requestOptions
);
    const json = await response.json();
return json;
} catch (error) {
return Promise.reject(error);
}
};
```

url formed => **http://localhost/api/communications/notifications/**

but when I pass the string to service from action and use that parameter (_url) it adds escape characters automatically
like this

**url formed => http://localhost/api/communications%E2%80%8B/notifications%E2%80%8B/**

here is my code of action file

```
import { notificationConstants } from '../constants/header.constants';
import * as ajaxService from '../services/ajax.service';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
export const notificationActions = { getAll };
function getAll() {
 return async (dispatch) => {
try {
  const res = await ajaxService.getAll(
    '/api/communications​/notifications​/'
  );
  dispatch(success(res));
} catch (error) {
  dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
   toast.error(error.toString());
  }
 };

function success(notification) {
return { type: notificationConstants.GET_ALL_NOTIFICATION, notification };
}
function failure(error) {
return { type: notificationConstants.GET_ALL_NOTIFICATION, error };
  }
 }
```

what is issue of this , please help.

**update:** Ive already tried **decodeURIComponent**

Comment: did you tried decodeURIComponent(`url`) ??

Comment: yes @AkhilAravind

Comment: what's in your ajaxService.getAll?

Comment: simple fetch api there @SomeoneSpecial

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. This might sound weird, but rerwite the entire string by hand. It is possible one of the characters is unicode if you copy-pasted the text. Visual code in my case says nothing, shows the caracter the same as always, but if you try to search the caracter in the entire code, you won't find it (as it is a different character).

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the entire string by hand works for me it strange behavior when you copy the string from swagger creating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answers by @bogdan-damaschin and @Asad works, but if you are curious which letters causes issues, you can paste URL string into this tool:

https://onlineasciitools.com/validate-ascii

Example:

(this string was copied from swagger docs page and contain 4 non-unicode characters)

[image]

After editing of URL string:

[image]